# wordpress pre and post content add div

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am styling a wordpress theme / template and I need to add a pre and post div to the content.

It would look something like this:

```
<div class="my-pre-content-div">This is added before the content</div>
<div id="content">
   All Content Here
</div>
<div class="my-post-content-div">This is added after the content</div>
```

I need to do this globally so what pages do I need to modify please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of php files, most of which will be template files, in this folder:

```
wp-content/themes/[your theme name]/
```

Comment: I'm already in the theme directory. I've got home.php and index.php.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your theme design but as a basic answer to this question you can use wp functions to page.php and single.php for global formating all posts and pages of your theme. you can use code bellow as an example:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="my-pre-content-div">This is added before the content</div>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
.
.
.
.
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
</div>
<div class="my-post-content-div">This is added after the content</div>
```